# Sending files from android to the MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, android

I want to send files  (.csv) from android  to the  MS SQL Server 2008 .  Shoud I use HTTPClient ?

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to move data from client(android) to server(sql server) in some networked environment, then one way could be to:

1. Create a stored procedure that [takes in the csv](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/) data
2. Create a web service that takes in the csv data(this calls the sp)
3. From your android call that web service(this calls the web service)